# How to run multiple test case from python nose test

Tags: python, unit-testing, nosetests

I am a newbie in process of learning python and currently working on a automation project.

And i have N numbers of testcase which needs to be run on reading material people suggest me to use nosetest.

What is the way to run multiple testcase using nosetest?

And is the correct approach doing it:

```
import threading
import time
import logging
import GLOBAL
import os
from EPP import EPP
import Queue
import unittest
global EPP_Queue
from test1 import test1
from test2 import test2


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='(%(threadName)-10s) %(message)s',
                    )
class all_test(threading.Thread,unittest.TestCase):

    def cleanup():
        if os.path.exists("/dev/epp_dev"):
            os.unlink("/dev/epp_dev")

    print "starts here"
    server_ip ='192.168.10.15'
    EppQueue = Queue.Queue(1)
    EPP = threading.Thread(name='EPP', target=EPP,
                           args=('192.168.10.125',54321,'/dev/ttyS17',
                           EppQueue,))
    EPP.setDaemon(True)
    EPP.start()
    time.sleep(5)

    suite1 = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(test1)
    suite2 = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(test2)
    return unittest.TestSuite([suite1, suite2])

    print "final"
    raw_input("keyy")
    def main():
        unittest.main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Read 
http://ivory.idyll.org/articles/nose-intro.html.

Download the package 
http://darcs.idyll.org/~t/projects/nose-demo.tar.gz

Follow the instructions provided in the first link.

Answer (score 0):

nosetest, when run from command line like 'nosetest' or 'nosetest-2.6' will recursively hunt for tests in the directory you execute it in.

So if you have a directory holding N tests, just execute it in that directory.  They will all be executed.

Comment: since it is a module based system which i am trying to arrive..i am trying to build a user selectable test system .where he will be having options running certain testcases and particular test.

Comment: can you jsu guide me how to do tht with nosetst and is my coding correct??